# Generating a 2-tuple from list and dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples, list-comprehension

I am looking for a Pythonic way to generate a 2-tuple from list and dictionary.

Currently I have a list and a dictionary.

Generating the list:

```
a_ids = ['A_%' % i for i in range(1,4)]

['A_1', 
 'A_2', 
 'A_3']
```

and the dictionary:

```
a_dict = [{'A': i} for i in range(1,4)]

[{'A': 1}, 
 {'A': 2}, 
 {'A': 3}]
```

What I would want to have is some way to return:

```
[('A_1', {'A': 1}),
 ('A_2', {'A': 2}),
 ('A_3', {'A': 3})]
```

I tried:

```
import itertools
list(itertools.product( (a_ids), (a_dict) ))
```

And it was close, but wrong :)
I understand why, in concept, but I am unsure how to correct it.

```
[('A_1', {'A': 1}),
 ('A_1', {'A': 2}),
 ('A_1', {'A': 3}),
 ('A_2', {'A': 1}),
 ('A_2', {'A': 2}),
 ('A_2', {'A': 3}),
 ('A_3', {'A': 1}),
 ('A_3', {'A': 2}),
 ('A_3', {'A': 3})]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want `zip`, not `itertools.product`:

```
both = zip(a_ids, a_dict)
```

Comment: Thanks @chepner! But I get as a return the memory address, 
so when I call 'both' I get <zip at 07fe0c....etc>

Comment: `zip` in Python 3 returns an iterator; just wrap the result in a list to get the actual tuples: `both = list(zip(a_ids, a_dict))`. (In Python 2, `zip` returned a concrete list, and `itertools.izip` returned an iterator. Python 3 made the iterator behavior the default for several function that previously returned lists.)

Answer (score 0):

In one line:

```
twople = [('A_%d' % i, {'A': i}) for i in range(1,4)]
```

You can use a single `for`, but use the index value in two places.

Output:

```
[('A_1', {'A': 1}),
 ('A_2', {'A': 2}),
 ('A_3', {'A': 3})]
```

Comment: Thanks @Prune, this is very handy, and I would use it but I need to have things separated as well for now, but it is quite handy to know this, thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

How about this: `[['A_%d'%i, {'A': i}] for i in range(1,4)]`

Comment: Some explanation would be helpful here!